# Using a different administration theme according to the role

Tags: 7, theming

Is there a way to use different administration themes according to the roles assigned to users?
I have two roles (admin, editor), and I want that, when creating content, users with the admin role use the garland theme, while users with the editor role use another theme.

Answer (score 6):

The [ThemeKey](https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey) module lets you set the theme using many different tests. While it doesn't specifically set admin theme in the usual way, it will certainly let you set a theme for a role and a path, achieving the same result. Some more details about this module (from its project page):

> ThemeKey allows you to define simple or sophisticated theme-switching rules which allow automatic selection of a theme depending on current path, taxonomy terms, language, node-type, and many, many other properties. It can also be easily extended to support additional properties exposed by other modules

Comment: +1 to give this more attention: I've used themekey in the past and it does just that. You can create "rules" to change the theme based on certain conditions including (but not limited to): path (/admin/%) and certain roles.

Answer (score 0):

The [Sections](https://www.drupal.org/project/sections) module can handle that for you.

Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... allows you to create sections within your site. Each section has an installed template, theme or style attached to it.
>
> Sections are shown based on:
>
> - Node specific visibility settings
> - Role specific visibility settings
> - Page specific visibility settings (regexped paths)
> - Custom PHP visibility snippets

Answer (score 0):

I want something like that you want, themes according to roles and I found the [Role Theme Switcher](https://www.drupal.org/project/role_theme_switcher) module, it is the best one for this job. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... assign separate themes for different roles (including anonymous) in your system.
>
> Often you want to separate Drupal administrative interface from frontend. You can do this assigning appropriate theme for you as user. What to do if you want to show different theme for non-authorized user?

**update:**
Role Theme Switcher can't set admin theme per user, use can use Themekey or [Themes By Role (TBR)](https://www.drupal.org/project/tbr) module

> About this Module
>
> This module comes out of a personal need to not want to use the same
> admin theme as the users and content editors of the sites I build.
> This module aims to fix that problem by allowing different themes to
> be enabled based on a user's role. Key Features
>
> ```
> Choose admin themes based on user role instead of a single admin theme for the whole site
>     Default site theme
>     Default admin theme
>     Any available theme
> ```